# Heroku could not detect rake tasks (LoadError: cannot load such file -- rspec/core/rake_task)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I'm using travisCI to deploy to heroku and I am getting this error. It has only just started happening.

I have the basic rails Rakefile and I have a file that looks like this as otherwise travis cannot detect the rake tasks:

```
# lib\tasks\spec.rake
require 'rspec/core/rake_task'
RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new
task :default => :spec
```

Why would this error be displaying specifically for heroku?

EDIT - I had a similar version to the (better) answer given:

```
begin
  require 'rspec/core/rake_task'
  desc "Run all examples"
  RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:spec) do |t|
    t.rspec_opts = %w[--color]
    t.pattern = 'spec/*_spec.rb'
  end
 rescue LoadError
end
```

Comment: Is rspec only in your bundle for development / production ?

Comment: @FrederickCheung it's just in the development group. Would this be the issue?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If rspec isn't in the production group (it generally isn't) then the code you posted would fail when run in a production environment like heroku.

In the rspec [docs](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/command-line/rake-task) they recommend doing this:

```
begin
  require 'rspec/core/rake_task'
  RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:spec)
rescue LoadError
end
```

So that the absence of rspec doesn't stop your rakefile loading.

Comment: Oh right. I had a slightly more complex version but commented out. I've added it to the post for reference.

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, I just faced the same issue. I fixed it by moving `rspec-rails` to production as shown below. I don't know why it works, but it works for me.

```
group :production, :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.8'
end
```

Comment: is it a good idea to put rspec-rails to production?