# Cannot push git repo to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, rubygems

I try to push my git repo to Heroku, but I get error:

```
remote: -----> Installing node-v12.16.2-linux-x64
remote: -----> Detecting rake tasks
remote: 
remote:  !
remote:  !     Could not detect rake tasks
remote:  !     ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app
remote:  !     and using the production group of your Gemfile.
remote:  !     /tmp/build_641166cf/bin/rake:8:in `require': cannot load such file -- rake (LoadError)
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote:  !
remote:  ! ## Warning - The same version of this code has already been built: 93a5bb6ab6e77c479f857031010316f9f372e20f
remote:  !
remote:  ! We have detected that you have triggered a build from source code with version 93a5bb6ab6e77c479f857031010316f9f372e20f
remote:  ! at least twice. One common cause of this behavior is attempting to deploy code from a different branch.
remote:  !
remote:  ! If you are developing on a branch and deploying via git you must run:
remote:  !
remote:  !     git push heroku <branchname>:main
remote:  !
remote:  ! This article goes into details on the behavior:
remote:  !   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/duplicate-build-version
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to whispering-fortress-58873.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/whispering-fortress-58873.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: не удалось отправить некоторые ссылки в «https://git.heroku.com/whispering-fortress-58873.git»
```

How to fix it? I've been trying to fix this for two days now.

- Ruby version: 2.7.2
- Rails version: 5.2.4.4
- Gem version: 3.1.4
- Bundler version: 2.2.7

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65542961/rails-rake-issue-when-deploying-to-heroku?noredirect=1#comment115918974_65542961)? Maybe bundler version is not supported?

Answer (score 0):

Checking error logs it seems that you need to push your branch to `main`

Try the following (or replace `master` with your current branch)

```
git push heroku master:main
```

Comment: which branch are you on?

Comment: ohh there's one more error can you try `bundle exec rake -P` and see if you get any errors

Comment: I'm on the master branch

Comment: @DeepakMahakate I also try it, but all is succefull